# Appending to list from while loop Python 3

Tags: list, loops, python-3.x

How can I append user int inputs to a list with a while loop? So whenever the number the user inputs is bigger than zero will be added to the list, but when it is a negative number the while loop will break and will continue to the next action. I am a total beginner in python 3, I tried a few things but didn't work. Here is what I tried :

```
numbers=[]
    number = int(input("Please input a number: "))
    while number>=0:
        numbers.append(number)
        if number <0:
            break
```

Comment: You never update `number` inside the `while` loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two logical errors there:

- First, you're never re-prompting for the number once you enter the `while` loop. You need to get a new number inside the loop so that you decide what to do upon the next iteration (append to the list, or stop the loop).
- Second, your test `if number < 0` is superfluous. Your loop runs only as long as number is greater or equal to zero; so inside the loop, there's no way the number can be smaller than zero. The test at the `while` above is quite sufficient.

Personally I'd rewrite the loop into an endless loop `while True: ...` and inside the loop I'd first prompt for a number. If that number were `<0`, I'd `break` out of the loop. Else, the remainder of the loop would be to append the new number to your list.

But there are countless solutions. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for-loop instead like this pseudo code

```
if number<0
    // do nothing or something or whatever
else:
    yourRange = range(0,number)
    for count in yourRange:
        numbers.append(number)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer!